# how to read keystorkes of keyboard in oracle forms 6i

Tags: oracleforms, keystroke

Hell EveryOne I am Trying to Read Key strokes in oracle forms 6i.My Requirement is that when i press any key or combination in oracle forms 6i then i want to display which key is pressed.Is there anyway to detect this in oracle forms 6i.

Comment: As far as I know there is no direct support for this in Forms. I guess it should be possible to do with a Java Bean. I you could explain is some more details what you requirements are then there may be some other way to implement this in Forms?

Comment: try this link: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/299947